# How fix bouncing scrollbar in a flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

When scrolling, the scrollbar changes its height and position not naturally.

Screen record: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xp7R.jpg

I tried: `ListView`, `SingleChildScrollView`
contents of both different and the same height
I already managed to figure out that the scrollbar normally works only when the content items have the same height

I also tried [flutter_draggable_scrollbar](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter-draggable-scrollbar) - there is a similar situation

Are there any working solutions?

```dart
Scrollbar(
  child: ListView(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Text(
          widget.digest.title,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 32,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      for (int i = 0; i < articles.length; i++)
        _builderListItem(articles[i], i + 1 == articles.length)
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Why don´t you use a Listview.builder? since you have a articles list, its better for performance to use the builder instead a normal listview.

Comment: I usually use it, this code is just an example.